# Search a file for a sequence of bytes (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, file-io, pattern-matching

I'm writing a C# application in which I need to search a file (could be very big) for a sequence of bytes, and I can't use any libraries to do so. So, I need a function that takes a byte array as an argument and returns the position of the byte following the given sequence. The function doesn't have to be fast, it simply has to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: How do the requirements of "very big" and "one byte array" fit together? Wouldn't you need support for multiple byte arrays with special support for the case where the searched sequence overlaps two bytearrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it doesn't have to be fast you could use this:

```
int GetPositionAfterMatch(byte[] data, byte[]pattern)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - pattern.Length; i++)
  {
    bool match = true;
    for (int k = 0; k < pattern.Length; k++)
    {
      if (data[i + k] != pattern[k])
      {
        match = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    if (match)
    {
      return i + pattern.Length;
    }
  }
}
```

But I really would recommend you to use Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm, it's the algorithm mostly used as a base of IndexOf methods for strings. The algorithm above will perform really slow, exept for small arrays and small patterns.

Comment: Should be i< (data.Length - pattern.Length) - then this theoretically works but is O(n*m) n = file length, m = pattern length

Answer (score 1):

The straight-forward approach as pointed out by Turrau works, and for your purposes is probably good enough, since you say it doesn't have to be fast - especially since for most practical purposes the algorithm is much faster than the worst case O(n*m). (Depending on your pattern I guess).

For an optimal solution you can also check out the [Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm), which makes use of partial matches which in the end is O(n+m).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extract of some code I used to do a boyer-moore type search. It's mean to work on pcap files, so it operates record by record, but should be easy enough to modify to suit just searching a long binary file. It's sort of extracted from some test code, so I hope I got everything for you to follow along. Also look up boyer-moore searching on wikipedia, since that is what it's based off of.

```
int[] badMatch = new int[256];
byte[] pattern;  //the pattern we are searching for

//badMath is an array of every possible byte value (defined as static later).
//we use this as a jump table to know how many characters we can skip comparison on
//so first, we prefill every possibility with the length of our search string
for (int i = 0; i < badMatch.Length; i++)
{
  badMatch[i] = pattern.Length;
}

//Now we need to calculate the individual maximum jump length for each byte that appears in my search string
for (int i = 0; i < pattern.Length - 1; i++)
{
  badMatch[pattern[i] & 0xff] = pattern.Length - i - 1;
}

// Place the bytes you want to run the search against in the payload variable
byte[] payload = <bytes>

// search the packet starting at offset, and try to match the last character
// if we loop, we increment by whatever our jump value is
for (i = offset + pattern.Length - 1; i < end && cont; i += badMatch[payload[i] & 0xff])
{
  // if our payload character equals our search string character, continue matching counting backwards
  for (j = pattern.Length - 1, k = i; (j >= 0) && (payload[k] == pattern[j]) && cont; j--)
  {
    k--;
  }
// if we matched every character, then we have a match, add it to the packet list, and exit the search (cont = false)
  if (j == -1)
  {
    //we MATCHED!!!
    //i = end;
    cont = false;
  }
}
```